# Where does Aluminum Hydroxide come from in a reduction of a ketone by LAH?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, organic-reduction

The experiment was done in a Laboratory. A ketone was reduced with LAH in THF under reflux.

At the end of the reaction, the protocol stated to add water until there is no more H2 released. The H2 might come from the reaction of water with unreacted LiAlH4 molecules.

What I don't seem to understand is that the protocol suggests adding acid to "dissolve aluminum hydroxide". I do not understand how lithium hydroxide can be formed in the first place and by which mechanism.

Comment: Ask yourself what is the species is formed after addition of hydride to the ketone. Is this species a base? What happens when water is added? Is the reaction mixture still basic?

Answer (score 2):

$\ce{LiAlH4}$ is not formed by $6$ independent ions. But, for the present purpose, it reacts as if it was formed of $\ce{Li^+ + Al^{3+} + 4 H^-}$. The ions $\ce{Li+}$ and $\ce{Al^{3+}}$ do  not react with water. The only ion reacting with water is the hydride ion $\ce{H^-}$, and the equation is $$\ce{H^- + H2O -> OH- + 1/2 H2}$$ As each $\ce{LiAlH4}$ "contains" $4$ hydride ions, these $4$ $\ce{H^-}$  produce also $4$ $\ce{OH-}$ ions with water, according to : $$\ce{4 H^- + 4 H2O -> 4 OH- + 2H2}$$ and these $4$ $\ce{OH-}$ may combine with the metallic ions $\ce{Li+}$ and $\ce{Al^{3+}}$ so as to give the following final equation  : $$\ce{LiAlH4 + 4 H2O -> LiOH + Al(OH)3 + 2 H2}$$ The aluminum hydroxide $\ce{Al(OH)3}$ is not soluble in water, but it passes into solution by adding some acid, like $\ce{HCl}$,  according to $$\ce{Al(OH)3 + 3 HCl -> AlCl3 + 3 H2O}$$